# Replace-function via EclipseLink on DB2 z/OS

Tags: db2, websphere, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, db2-zos

I am migrating an application from JPA 2.0 with OpenJPA on WebSphere 8.5 to JPA 2.1 with EclipseLink on WebSphere 9.0, using DB2 12 on z/OS. Generally it is working, but one rather complex query is failing. I could localize the problem to the usage of a custom DB2-function call within a criteria-query. The call looks something like this:

```
criteriaBuilder.function("REPLACE", String.class, fromMyEntity.get("myField"), criteriaBuilder.literal("a"), criteriaBuilder.literal("b"));
```

This produces the following error (had to translate some error texts, since WebSphere localizes them, and anonymize my field/table names, so labels/names might not be 100% exact):

```
Error: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.WAS-v20160414-bd51c70): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-171, SQLSTATE=42815, SQLERRMC=2;REPLACE, DRIVER=3.72.44
Errorcode: -171
Call: SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE REPLACE(MYFIELD, ?, ?) LIKE ?
bind => [abc, def, %g%]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=MyEntity sql="SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE REPLACE(MYFIELD, ?, ?) LIKE ?").
```

What really confuses me, if I take the generated query, replace the placeholders with the given bound parameters, and execute that in a database client myself, it works without error.

The documentation states, the first parameter must not be empty (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_replace.html), and indeed if I use an empty string either as a literal in the query or in my database client, it will produce the above error. But none of the rows in the database contain an empty value. There are checks in place to prevent this in the old environment, but they don't appear to work with the new environment, so I disabled them while searching for the problem, and made sure myself no empty values exist. I can even use the primary key as the first parameter, and it will still fail, and that can't even contain an empty/null value.

Using other functions (like TRANSLATE) works, I also tried using "SYSIBM.REPLACE" as name, and different combinations of parameters, but as soon as I use a real column to replace data in, it fails. Anybody got any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

This is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_TABLE" (
"ID" INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE NO CYCLE CACHE 20 NO ORDER ), 
"MYFIELD" VARCHAR(160) FOR MIXED DATA WITH DEFAULT NULL,
[....]
) IN "<Database>"."<Tablespace>" PARTITION BY SIZE EVERY 4 G AUDIT NONE DATA CAPTURE NONE CCSID UNICODE;
```

Comment: What is the Db2-datatype and encoding for the column MYFIELD (the first argument to the replace function) ?

Comment: The problem is not in the database, but in the value of the bound parameter that apparently comes from your code: `SQLCODE=-171, SQLSTATE=42815, SQLERRMC=2;REPLACE` means the second parameter of the function, the string to be replaced, is the problem.

Comment: @mao it's varchar(160), and encoding should be unicode. I added the ddl to the question.

Comment: @mustaccio I think you're right, if I use a column instead of a literal as the second parameter it works. But how do I get it to work with a literal?

Comment: @mustaccio **edit** It only works though if I leave out the third parameter. It I use a literal as the third parameter, the SQLERRMC changes to "3;REPLACE". But that parameter may be even be left empty, and the call should still work. So why doesn't the "REPLACE" function work with literals? "TRANSLATE" for example works...